# Sort an array by its relative position

Tags: javascript, sorting

Example object array:

```js
[{
    id: 'a',
    beforeId: null
}, {
    id: 'b',
    beforeId: 'c'
}, {
    id: 'c',
    beforeId: 'a'
}, {
    id: 'd',
    beforeId: 'b'
}]
```

Output order: `d-b-c-a`; each element sorted relative to each other element based on its `beforeId` property.

I could make a temporary array and sort the above array. Is sorting possible with `array.sort`?

Comment: @deceze - You could simply do something like: `array.sort((a, b) => a.val < b.val)`

Comment: @scagood Nope. 1) The callback is supposed to return <0, 0 or >0, not a boolean. 2) That's not the criterion here. (I admit you'll have to do a double take to see it, but this question isn't half bad.)

Comment: The thing that is confusing be is that val:`d-b-c-a` doesn't seem to be in order of anything (beforeId: `b-c-a-null`) I would expect either `a-c-d-b` or `c-d-b-a`

Comment: It's basically a sort starting from the right. The element with beforeId 'null' will be the last element and all other elements will find their order from that element. I'm trying to hack it together using `charCodeAt()` to transform the string into a number you can use to sort, but it's not going to be pretty code. We'll get this to work, but i'd strongly advcie to find a better sorting mechanism.

Comment: @scagood D before B, B before C, C before A, A before nothing (last).

Comment: @deceze, I realise this, just beforeId:`null-a-b-c` => val:`a-c-d-b` and beforeId:`a-b-c-null` => val:`c-d-b-a` neither of which are `d-b-c-a` (`b-c-a-null`)

Comment: A regular sorting function if of no use here because by examining the first two items there is no way to tell their order. Each item is linked only to its immediate neighbours but sorting does not work this way.

Comment: @scagood I've tried to make it more obvious… it's literally in the name: `before` `id`.

Comment: Looks like you have a "directed acyclic graph".

Comment: Ah I get it now. It only worked because the source array is already sorted by id. Is that the fluke you mentioned deceze? Since moving the elements around in the source array indeed produces a different result.

Comment: @Shilly - It's a little bit more than just that, even if they were sorted by id in a larger array it would fall face first, If you generate a larger array (for example using: https://gist.github.com/scagood/b6d8bba0a70a8af55fad0d6caf3d45cc) (I've just thrown this together so it may be buggy) then try the original sort you'll see it's flaws

Answer (score 7):

You could build an object with the relations and generate the result by using the object with `beforeId: null` and unshift all objects for the result array.

The next object is the one with the actual `val` as key.

Complexity: O(2n).

```js
function chain(array) {
    var o = {}, pointer = null, result = [];

    array.forEach(a => o[a.beforeId] = a);

    while (o[pointer]) {
        result.unshift(o[pointer]);
        pointer = o[pointer].val;
    }

    return result;
}

var data = [{ val: 'a', beforeId: null }, { val: 'b', beforeId: 'c' }, { val: 'c', beforeId: 'a' }, { val: 'd', beforeId: 'b' }];

console.log(chain(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This one is over ten times faster in my environment (test at: https://gist.github.com/scagood/097295617c204f06728e1fa5c9393f8c)

Answer (score 4):

This is a terribly inefficient and naïve algorithm, but it works:

```js
const array = [
    {id: 'a', beforeId: null},
    {id: 'b', beforeId: 'c'},
    {id: 'c', beforeId: 'a'},
    {id: 'd', beforeId: 'b'}
];

// find the last element
const result = [array.find(i => i.beforeId === null)];

while (result.length < array.length) {
    // find the element before the first element and prepend it
    result.unshift(array.find(i => i.beforeId == result[0].id));
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is sorting possible with array.sort?

sure, with a helper function:

```js
graph = [
    {id: 'a', beforeId: null},
    {id: 'b', beforeId: 'c'},
    {id: 'c', beforeId: 'a'},
    {id: 'd', beforeId: 'b'}
];

let isBefore = (x, y) => {
    for (let {id, beforeId} of graph) {
        if (id === x)
            return (beforeId === y) || isBefore(beforeId, y);
    }
    return false;
};

graph.sort((x, y) => x === y ? 0 : (isBefore(x.id, y.id) ? -1 : +1))

console.log(graph);
```

`isBefore` returns true if `x` is before `y` immediately or transitively.

For generic, non-linear topological sorting see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms

UPD: As seen [here](https://gist.github.com/scagood/097295617c204f06728e1fa5c9393f8c), this turned out to be horribly inefficient, because `sort` involves many unnecessary comparisons. Here's the fastest (so far) version:

```
function sort(array) {
    let o = {}, res = [], len = array.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
        o[array[i].beforeId] = array[i];

    for (let i = len - 1, p = null; i >= 0; i--) {
        res[i] = o[p];
        p = o[p].id;
    }

    return res;
}
```

which is the @Nina's idea, optimized for speed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach :

```
// order(null, vals, []) = ["d", "b", "c", "a"]
function order(beforeId, vals, result){
    var id = beforeId || null;

    var before = vals.filter(function(val){
                return val.beforeId ===  id
    });

    if (before.length === 0) return result;   

    return order(before[0].val,
                    vals, 
                [before[0].val].concat(result));
}
```